# Postgresql 11 Partitioning detail tables based on column in master table in foreign-key relationship

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

The improvements to declarative range-based partitioning in version 11 seem like they can really work for my use case, but I'm not completely sure how foreign keys work with partitions.

I have tables `Files -< Segments -< Entries` in which there are hundreds of Segments per File and hundreds of Entries per segment, so Entries is on the order of 10,000 times the size of Files. Files have a CreationDate field and customers will define a retention period so they'll drop old Entries.  All of this clearly points to date-based partitions so it's quicker to query the most recent entries first, and easy to drop old ones.

The first issue I encounter is that when I try to create the Files table, it sounds like I have to include createdDate as part of the primary key in order to have it in the RANGE partition:

```
CREATE TABLE Files2
  (
    FileId BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    createdDate timestamp with time zone,
    filepath character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL
  ) PARTITION BY RANGE (createdDate)
  WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
  )                                
  TABLESPACE pg_default;
ERROR:  insufficient columns in PRIMARY KEY constraint definition
DETAIL:  PRIMARY KEY constraint on table "files2" lacks column "createddate" which is part of the partition key.
```

If I drop the "PRIMARY KEY" from the definition of FileId, I don't get the error, but does that affect the efficiency of child lookups?

I also don't know how to declare the partitions for the child table. `PARTITION BY RANGE (Files.createdDate)` doesn't work.

Since it's only in version 11 that this use case would even be possible, I haven't found much information about it and would appreciate any pointers!  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I believe it is a new feature of the version 11. There is a document from which you can get the following information:

"A primary key constraint must include a partition key column. Attempting to create a primary key constraint that does not contain partitioned columns results in an error"

https://h50146.www5.hpe.com/products/software/oe/linux/mainstream/support/lcc/pdf/PostgreSQL11NewFeaturesGAen20181022-1.pdf

Comment: This article improves the answer and gives examples. 
https://minimalistic-oracle.blogspot.com/2019/01/how-to-create-partitioned-table-with.html

Comment: Or add your `id` along with partitioning fields into a separate `UNIQUE INDEX`.